# Install ffmpeg in windows 7 x64

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I have a problem to install ffmpeg, I tried several tutorials but did not.
I tried using the dll and executables but could not get the result is always.

```
"Fatal error: Call to undefined function dl ()"
```

I went on the official website and downloaded the dlls did the procedure in playing in system32 and php / ex and declared the extension in php.ini but does not work.
I am using the version of php 5.3.13.
I was thinking it was the version of php what do you think? I'm using WampServer observation

Comment: And why do you use `dl()`?

Answer (score 0):

I used the ffmpeg-20130318-git-519ebb5-win64-static.7z from http://partisans9.alamaree.com/chan-5973786/all_p2.html

It is working, though I used it through command line for file format conversion only.